# How to add extensions to an existing certificate using Bouncy Castle

Tags: key, bouncycastle, identifier, subject, authority

Now I have a certificate without extensions such as 'authority key identifier' and 'subject key identifier'. How can I add these extensions to the existing certificate using Bouncy Castle or other jars? If impossible, how can I create a certificate with all extensions listed in RFC 5280 using Java or Python?

Comment: The contents of a certificate are signed (including its extensions). If the certificate is already generated, you can not modify it. You will need to issue a new certificate.

Comment: How to create a new certificate with unchanged content in the old version certificate and new content which replaces corresponding part in the old version certificate?